# Can I get request body as string in .Net 5.0?

Tags: c#, json, .net, http, post

We have a http server. The server receive http post requests with json body. But sometimes the json object came invalid. In this case we want to read body as string. How can i implement that in .Net 5.0.

Thanks.

My Code :

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api")]
        public async Task<string> api([FromBody] string requestContent)
        {
             // When invalid json request receieve, requestContent is null  
           return requestContent;
        }
```

Comment: The FromBody element is in Json. you can get string values if you specify each property individually. Also, what exceptions do you get and can you post an example of the Json you receive?

Comment: add valid and invalid JSON , it easy to others

Comment: I think i can not explain my problem correctly. I want to get a request body (or all request with header) as string. Than i parse that string in my methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the body outside of controller flow. But firstly, you should activate request body buffering.
On the `Configure` method of `Startup` class use this middleware before `app.UseEndpoints`.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
   context.Request.EnableBuffering();
   await next.Invoke();
});
```

Then you can read body from any action like this:

```
Request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
var body = await new StreamReader(Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well better would be rather than sending the body as json, you should send as string format. For examples with the current code snippet provided by you:

request :

```
"{\"username\":\"ak\", \"password\": \"142437630028jdnj\"}"
```

response :

```
{"username":"ak", "password": "142437630028jdnj"}
```

You have to parse the json body to string before sending them like below:

```
JObject.Parse(str);
```